# Растянуть блок на всю высоту родителя

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как растянуть блок `main__container` на всю высоту родителя `main`, чтобы сетка grid заполнила весь `main`?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__container"></div>
        </header>
        
        
        <main class="main">
            <div class="main__container">
                <div class="main__card big">
                    <p>
                    text1
                    </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="main__card">
                    <p>
                    text1
                    </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="main__card">
                    <p>
                    text1
                    </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="main__card">
                    <p>
                    text1
                    </p>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
        </main>
        
        
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="footer__container"></div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    height: 70px;
    background: grey;
}

.main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.main__container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.big {
    grid-row: span 3;
    background: red;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 70px;
    background: grey;
}

[class*="__container"] {
    max-width: 1230px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

задай высоту хедеру и мейну в % типа

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background: grey;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```